# Как устранить ошибку при использовании AutoScroll с#?

Tags: c#, winforms

В `flowLayotPanel1` создаются динамические `Picturebox`, при использовании элемента `AutoScroll` вылетает программа и выдает ошибку, как это исправить?

```
private void btn_scrennshot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pb = new PictureBox();
    var name = new Label();
    var chbx = new CheckBox();

    try
    {
        Mat m = new Mat();
        capture.Retrieve(m);
        pb.Image = m.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Flip(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FlipType.None).Bitmap;
        pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        pb.Height = pb.Image.Height / 3;
        pb.Width = pb.Image.Width / 3;
        name.Text = $"SMV_{textBox_surename.Text + DateTime.Now.Hour + DateTime.Now.Minute + DateTime.Now.Second}";
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb);
        pb.Controls.Add(chbx);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}

private void flowLayoutPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

код ошибки

`System.AccessViolationException: "Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена."`

окно с кодом выдает такое (чет я не придал значение, возможно это даст больше информации)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SOFIA_Vision
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Главная точка входа для приложения.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: В какой строчке ошибка, есть стектрейс?

Comment: На каком именно моменте вылет?

Comment: Возможно ваш ``capture.Retrieve(m);`` был Disposed, проверьте с помощью точки останова.

Comment: -  $exception {"Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена."} System.AccessViolationException.    на моменте когда столбик скрола вверх-вниз передвигаю

Comment: @Blackmeser добавил информации посмотри пожалуйста, может так яснее проблема будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего смысл в том, что битмапы, переданные в `PictureBox` ссылаются на участок памяти, который освобождается до того как вы его перестаете использовать.

Это ошибка неуправляемого кода, когда что-то пытается обратиться к участку памяти по указателю, ссылающемуся на недоступный текущему приложению участок оперативной памяти. То есть память была не выделена или освобождена. В вашем случае, скорее всего второе.

Чтобы этого избежать, нужно создать свой собственный `Bitmap` и скопировать туда картинку.

```
pb.Image = new Bitmap(m.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Flip(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FlipType.None).Bitmap);
```

Comment: Спасибо! протестировал раз 10 ни разу не вылетела